# Prev and next buttons to change divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a code in jQuery that adds the class active to the next div and removes it from the previous div and vice versa with the previous. This all in mind with animations I want to add later.

If you want to see the code with HTML and CSS:
http://codepen.io/salman15/pen/kXVmRG?editors=1010

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#next').click(function() {
        var location = $(this).parent().parent();
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('div').next('#case').addClass('active');
    });

    $('#prev').click(function() {
        var location = $(this).parent().parent();
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).prev('#case').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please describe more what problem you are having ?

Comment: The code does not add the code to the active class to the next div, but to all the divs. and does not add the class at all to the previous one

Comment: Your HTML is invalid - you've repeated the `#case` and the `#tX` elements multiple times. `id` attributes must be unique

Comment: but how would i pass on the active class to the next sibling then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not give your `div` elements the same `id` value: that is invalid HTML. Instead use *"case"* as a `class` value.

To apply the *active* class you can just chain to the *removeClass* method, find the next `div`, and apply *addClass* to that element.

Here is a simplified snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#next').click(function(){
    if ($('.active').next('.case').length) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active')
                    .next('.case')
                    .addClass('active');
    }
  });
  $('#prev').click(function(){
    if ($('.active').prev('.case').length) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active')
                    .prev('.case')
                    .addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active { background: yellow; border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="next">
  <h1>next</h1>
</div>
<div id="prev">
  <h1>prev</h1>
</div>
<div class="case active">content 1</div>
<div class="case">content 2</div>
<div class="case">content 3</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, why is it bad too use the same id?

Comment: The HTML standards say it must be unique. DOM Methods expect this rule to be true. If you don't keep to this rule, you get unexpected results. So for instance, `$('#case')` will never return more than one match, even if you have given more elements that same id.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the knowledge!

Comment: If you don't mind i have one more question, while editing your code i've run into an error. I can keep pressing next and prev when i've hit the last div



http://codepen.io/salman15/pen/rLRZrJ

Comment: The condition `($('.in1,.in2,.in3').next('.t1,.t2,.t3').length)` will be true also when (for example) `.in2` has a `t3` as next sibling, in which case you would need false. You should just test one of them, like this: `($('.in1').next('.t1').length)`. If you have more questions like this, could I suggest that you create a new question for it? That way you'll have more ppl looking at it, and there is also some reward for both you and those that answer.

Comment: will do, just didn't want to come off as if the code was mine

Comment: That really is no problem ;-) If you want (but its not necessary), you can link in a new follow-up question to this question to help readers understand the history/background.

Comment: I had done that, but your answer has once again helped me! You have my thanks!

if you're interested in seeing the result:

http://codepen.io/salman15/pen/rLRZrJ?editors=1010

Comment: Nice result. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML and JS is quite flawed as @rory-mccrossan pointed out in the comments.

Here's a really simple example how I would do it.

```js
$(function() {
    var nextBtn = $("#next"),
        prevBtn = $("#prev");
  
    nextBtn.on('click', function(e) {
        var active = $(".active");
        var next = active.next('.case');
        if (next.length) {
            active.removeClass('active');
            next.addClass('active');
        }
    });
    prevBtn.on('click', function(e) {
        var active = $(".active");
        var prev = active.prev('.case');
        if (prev.length) {
            active.removeClass('active');
            prev.addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="case active">One</li>
  <li class="case">Two</li>
  <li class="case">Three</li>
  <li class="case">Four</li>
</ul>
<button id="prev">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

The `next.length` and `prev.length` checks are there so that when you get to the end of the list, it won't go past it.

Answer (score 2):

```
//file
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $('.d1 li.s1').click(function(){
   $('li').removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  });
  $('ul.ddd li.ggg').click(function(){
    $('li').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
 $(".next").click(function(){
 i=1
            var $toHighlight = $('.active').next().length > 0 ? $('.active').next() : $('#MainMenu li.s1').first();
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $toHighlight.addClass('active');
            });


         $(".previous").click(function(){
            var $toHighlight = $('.active').prev().length > 0 ? $('.active').prev() : $('ul.mainmenu1 li.s1').last(); 

            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $toHighlight.addClass('active');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add custom classes to divs you want to change e.g div-1, div-2.
2. Add a counter that will indicate which div is active.
3. On clicking NEXT or PREV increment or decrement this counter, remove active class from all divs and add it  to item with div-{counter} class.
4. Remember to disable NEXT button when the counter is bigger then number of your divs and disable PREV button when the counter is smaller then 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ggg').click(function(){
   $('.ggg,.sss').removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(this).next();
  });

 var x22 = $( "#MainMenu" ).find( ".ggg" ).length;
 //alert(x22);

 var i = 118;
    var hrefa2;
      $(".previous").click(function () {

      hrefa = $( "#MainMenu").find(".ggg").eq(i).attr("alt");
       //hrefa3 = $("#MainMenu").find(".ggg").eq(0);
     i--;
    //alert(hrefa);
     $('.ggg').removeClass("active");
    $( "#MainMenu" ).find( ".ggg" ).eq(i).addClass("active");
 });

  var i = 0;
    var hrefa;
      $(".next").click(function () {

      hrefa = $( "#MainMenu").find(".ggg").eq(i).attr("alt");
      //hrefa1 = $("#MainMenu").find(".ggg").eq(0);
     i++;
    //alert(hrefa);
     $('.ggg').removeClass("active");
    $( "#MainMenu" ).find( ".ggg" ).eq(i).addClass("active");
 });
```

Comment: Please add explanation supporting your answer.